# PHP How to prevent conflicts between identical files

Tags: php

I have 3 php scripts:

```
script1.php
script2.php
script3.php
```

I'm running these files simultaneously, the content of the scripts are identical, same variable and workload.

My question is: Will this cause any conflicts between the files? I have many variables and at each file, I unset the variables to free them in the RAM. So basically if script1.php did the job and unset the variables, will this cause script2.php to lose data from script2.php variables before finishing the work? Or is it true that each file is independent of any other PHP file?

Comment: No, they do not talk to each other in Any Way At All. If they are all the same, you could just have one of them and it could be run simultaneously by 1000 users and still there would be no connection between them

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each file is independent. In fact, if you only had one file, and 40 people requested it at the same time, none of the variables inside would intermix, giving one person's data to another person.

Comment: The only way one visitor could see the data from another would be if you were storing the data in a file or database. If you're only using variables, the data won't bleed from one user to the next.